# Have ServiceBus respect transaction scope?

Tags: c#, azure, atomic, azureservicebus

Within code I need to atomically:

```
//write to a database table
//publish EventA to service bus
//write to another database table
//publish EventB to service bus
```

If either of the db writes fails, I can easily roll everything back within a transaction scope. However if that happens, it's essential the events are never published to service bus.

Ideally I need the service bus library to 'wait until the transaction scope successfully completes' before publishing the message onto the bus.

I'm working with legacy .net framework code - I could easily write something which holds events to raise in memory, and only raise these once the scope completes. The problem even then is that if EventB fails to publish, EventA has already been published.

What's the easiest way to include service bus events within a transaction scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's an easy way to address this. Azure Service Bus will not share a transaction with any other service. Just as database transactions cannot include a web service call. The way to go about it would always require some additional complexity compared to a simple DTC transaction that was possible on-premises (to an extent).

But it can be done. With the patterns such as Outbox (unit of work) and Inbox (idempotency) are described very well in [this](https://event-driven.io/en/outbox_inbox_patterns_and_delivery_guarantees_explained/) post

> **Outbox Pattern** - This pattern ensures that a message was sent (e.g. to a queue) successfully at least once. With this pattern, instead of directly publishing a message to the queue, we store it in the temporary storage (e.g. database table). We’re wrapping the entity save and message storing with the Unit of Work (transaction). By that, we’re making sure that if the application data was stored, the message wouldn’t be lost. It will be published later by a background process. This process will check if there are any not sent events in the table. When the worker finds such messages, it tries to send them. After it gets confirmation of publishing (e.g. ACK from the queue) it marks the event as sent.

> **Inbox Pattern** - This is a pattern similar to Outbox Pattern. It’s used to handle incoming messages (e.g. from a queue). Accordingly, we have a table in which we’re storing incoming events. Contrary to outbox pattern, we first save the event in the database, then we’re returning ACK to queue. If save succeeded, but we didn’t return ACK to queue, then delivery will be retried. That’s why we have at-least-once delivery again. After that, an outbox-like process runs. It calls message handlers that perform business logic.

To answer your specific question.

> What's the easiest way to include service bus events within a transaction scope?

The simplest would be to use a library that does that already, has been tested thoroughly, and can integrate into your system. [MassTransit](https://masstransit-project.com/), [NServiceBus](https://particular.net/nservicebus), [Jasper](https://jasperfx.github.io/), etc. Alternatively, build your own. I'd not advise unless it's a pet project or the core of your system.